# write a efficient code in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, coding-style

I have a controller with many actions which routes to different pages

```
def act1
 @a=...
 @b=....
 @c=...
end

def act1
 @a=...
 @b=....
 @c=...
end

def act2_ajax
 @a=...
 @b=....
 @c=...
end

def act3
 @a=...
 @b=....
 @c=...
end

def act4_ajax
 @a=...
 @b=....
 @c=...
end
```

i want to write these variables in a seperate action and just call the action name, i have used variables @a, @b @c in views so if i call a seperate action these variables should come

for ex lets say we write

```
def common(xx)
  @a=...
  @b=...
  @c=...
end
```

we call common inside act1 like

```
def act1
  self.common1(var)
end
```

which whould output like

```
def act1 
  @a=...
  @b=...
  @c=...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
before_action :set_vars, only: [:act1, :act2, :act3]

private
  def set_vars
    @a = ...
    @b = ...
    @c = ...
  end
```

And no additional lines in your actions!

Comment: the question is tagged with `ruby-on-rails-3` and `before_action` has been introduced in Rails 4.0.0, so you meant perhaps `before_filter`